# Anyone know what key this cadence from the SimCity 3000 theme is in?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, analysis

I'm currently analyzing the SimCity 3000 theme (

). I've noticed that the chords for the intro (by figuring out the notes for each chord and then looking the note combinations up) are `Eb major -> C major -> F/A major -> Eb major -> C major`.

What key is this cadence in??? C major? Eb major? ...And what exactly is the F/A chord all about?

Edit: I think the key might be F Major (making the cadence `bVII -> V -> I6 (?) -> bVII -> V`), but I'm not so sure.

Comment: According to the song's score, it is in the key of C major. I'd argue that the accidentals are step-wise modulation to Bb major. As for the F/A, the score for this piece indicates it is a root position F chord. It more or less functions as a pivot chord, being the "common denominator" between the keys of C and Bb.

Comment: Either way, I believe this question is off topic as individual song analysis is not part of Stack exchanges' guidelines. "Questions about transcribing or finding a particular song, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers." There is a legitimate question in here though. If you could edit your post to focus on the progression itself and not the song, it shouldn't get flagged/closed.